# recovering a raid 0 after reinstalling windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid, raid-0

thanks in advance for your help,

I have made a clean install of windows 7 to my system today to an SSD, along the ssd I have another ssd and 2x 1tb disks in Raid0. Only difference to the former installation being that the new one is UEFI.

But the raid does no show in explorer.

In disk manager disks are listed as "disk 2" and "disk 3", both as Dynamic and external. When a try to "import" as I readed in this forum, by right clicking, seems that windows knows that are part of an array, but trying to restore it shows me the message "invalid package name" (or something alike since my windows is in Spanish) and gives me no other option but convert to a "basic disk" (don`t think that would be a good idea)

Has anyone get the same error? Any ideas?

Sorry for my horrible English, I hope is understandable.

pc: MSI gaming3 / intel 4790k / 24gigs 1600mhz / msi 780

Comment: How were they configured in RAID before? in Windows, in the BIOS?

Comment: Sorry! I configured the raid via windows, with the disk manager!

Comment: Edit: not sure but could be that what appears like Externo to me stands for "foreign" in the English version of windows.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

As incredible as it is, foreign disk could not be imported because the name of the computer had been changed using a non valid caracter!
Former name was makina (stands for machine) wen I reinstalled I called Temüjin (first name of Gengis Khan) meaning the most fine steel ;) AND THAT WAS THE PROBLEM,

I keept receiving the "Invalid pack name" when trying to import the 2 disks of my raid0 because of that "ü" of temüjin!!!!!!

Changed the name of the rig to temujin, reboot, imported de foreign disks and voilá! problem solved!my raid0 is back and fine.

thanks Darth Android for your interest. Hope this can help others.

Comment: I hope puting this link will not be a problem since is more info about the issue. http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02099658